# Why does Lagrange Multipliers work?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-spaces, vectors, lagrange-multiplier

I'm trying to understand why the method of Lagrange multipliers is legit.

If I'm trying to find min/max of a function $f(x,y)$ subject to constraint $g(x,y)=c$

then as per my professor $\mathbf {at \ the \ constrained \ min/max, \ the \ rate \ of \ change \ of \ f \ must \ be \ zero \ in \ any \ direction \ along \ g=c}$.

I cannot seem to understand this statement.

But this is the elementary part of the proof;

coz based on this he says $\frac{df}{ds}_\hat u = \nabla f.\hat u = 0$ where $\hat u$ is tangent to g=c

$\mathbf {Why \ is \ \hat u\ tangent \ to \  g=c ? \ Is \ this \ based \ on \ the \ fact \ that \ at \ the \ constrained \ min/max \ g=c \ is \ tangent \ to \ f?}$

and the rest is understable that such $\nabla g$ is perpendicular to $\hat u$ that is the tangent and hence $\nabla f$ and $\nabla g$ are parallel finally yielding that $\nabla f = \lambda \cdot\nabla g $

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do Lagrange Multipliers work?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1290487/why-do-lagrange-multipliers-work)

Comment: See also [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/23958/742).

Comment: why should rate of change of f be zero along g=c?

Comment: It's not zero along all of the curve, only at the point where $f$ has its maximum value - you're essentially applying the extreme value theorem.